# Sumifs + Match + Index functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to use the sumifs function with a function to lookup a sheet name that matches a cell in the same sheet. Example Cell B1 has the "sheetname", cell A2 has the name of what I need to match on "sheetname". If the name is found multiple times within "sheetname", sum column N. I can't seem to make it work, any help?

Comment: You want INDIRECT not INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(B1 & "!A:A"),A2,INDIRECT(B1 & "!N:N"))
```

This assumes that the name to be searched in column A on the desired sheet.